# Build QtWebkit with V8

Tags: webkit, qt4, v8, qtwebkit

For some days I've been looking forward to build `QtWebkit` with `V8` support.

I found lot of resources over the internet, some of them old like this one from 2010:

- http://webkit.sed.hu/blog/20101216/benchmarking-qtwebkit-v8-linux

> "For some time it has been possible to build and run QtWebKit on Linux
>   using Google's V8 JavaScript engine instead of the default
>   JavaScriptCore."

And this one from 2011:

- https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-qt/2011-January/001111.html

> The current trunk should also build now with:
>   Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --qt --v8

I also found this one:

- http://qt-project.org/wiki/V8_Port

> THE PROJECT WAS ABANDONED [bugreports.qt-project.org]

The `--v8` doesn't seems to be recognized in Webkit's `build_webkit` script and there doesn't seems to be a similar option.

A `find` in Webkit's source revealed v8 tests and bindings existing in the project.

So it's there a way to build `QtWebkit` with `v8` or is it abandoned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People at #qtwebkit (freenode.net) said that V8 support was abandoned.

But I found this that may be worth trying:

- https://github.com/qtwebkit-v8ers/qtwebkit-v8

Comment: Do you have any further findings on this? I'm also looking for this! The git link seems to be down.